# How can I tether an Android-based phone to a Linux with Bluetooth and Internet access?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, router

The web is chock-full of explanations on how to tether device so-and-so (including Linux-based devices) *to* an Android phone providing the Internet uplink.

I'd like to do it *the other way around*. I'd like to be able to use a small Linux-based router with a Bluetooth dongle as the uplink for my Android phone, tethering my Android phone via Bluetooth PAN.

I can set up the Android side. How do I set up the GNU/Linux side?

1. Is this at all currently possible?
2. How do I do it?

I am running Android 10 (the connecting device) and I am flexible with the Linux side (currently it's either Debian or OpenWRT, depending on the device I try) offering the tether via Bluetooth and the uplink as well as routing.

NB: I'd like to emphasize that I am *not* interested in WiFi-based solutions. I need this via Bluetooth, i.e. PAN.

Comment: What have you got working: I would think that you first need to get them both on the same network (pair the devices). Then (if it was wifi, and maybe the same), set up DHCP on the Gnu/Linux (for this interface only). Then set up routing in Gnu/Linux, and add this to DHCP (to announce it). Then test to see what is left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need something like [this](https://www.mulgara.org/images/1/15/ELC_NA_2019_PPT_CreatingBT_PAN_RNDIS_router_using_OpenWrt_20190814r1.pdf) (Let me copy the relevant part here, just in case):

First of all, you need to enable BT PAN support in your OPENWRT firmware:

```
$ git clone https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt/openwrt.git/
$ cd openwrt
$ ./scripts/feeds update -a
$ ./scripts/feeds install -a
$ cp enable_btpan_usbrndis_for_wzr-hz-g300nh.seed .config
$ make defconfig
$ make
```

After flashing your image to router, use bluetoothctl to turn on your dongle

```
bluetoothctl power on
```

ssh login to OpenWrt and set NAP UUID to bluetoothd:

```
dbus-send --system
--dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0
--type=method_call
org.bluez.NetworkServer1.Register
string:“00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb”
string:"br-lan"
```

Check, if bluetoothd supports NAP role by running `bluetoothd show`. It should show something like this:

```
Controller 00:1B:DC:06:61:D4 (public)
Name: BlueZ 5.49
Alias: BlueZ 5.49
Class: 0x00020000
Powered: yes
Discoverable: no
Pairable: yes
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: NAP (00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: PnP Information (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Access Profile (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
Modalias: usb:v1D6
```

Set your device (phone) as trusted in advance (substitute MAC with your own, obviously):

```
root@OpenWrt:~# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# trust 00:02:5B:00:A5:A5
[CHG] Device 00:02:5B:00:A5:A5 Trusted: yes
Changing 00:02:5B:00:A5:A5 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]#
```

Make BT discoverable on OpenWrt router and pair to it from Android device. Then tick "Use for Internet access" checkbox in device properties.

`bnep0` interface, belonging to `br-lan` bridge should appear in OpenWRT at this stage.